# Can't rewrite url to proxy in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to host a [Bower repository](https://github.com/Hacklone/private-bower/) behing an nginx proxy. However, I can't find out how to configure this properly. I want to strip the `/bower` from the beginning of the url. I currently have the following configuration.

```
location /bower {
  rewrite /bower/(.*) /$1  break;
  proxy_pass         http://localhost:5678;
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

Using this configuration, the `/bower` part is still not stripped when the request is made to the bower repository behind the proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make that:

```
location /bower/ {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5678/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

Note the added slashes on the location and the proxy_pass.
Is the proxy_set_header necessary for the bower backend?

Edit: this is described quite well in the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: I'm not sure whether those are necessary, but your answer works. Thanks!

Comment: The exact URL `/bower` won't be served by this location block aymore while it was kinda processed in the original post. Changing the original rewrite to `/bower/*(.*) /$1 break;` would have done it.